# WPF component in unit testing

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

I'm coding a Unit testing and for debug purposes I do need to see some data (please do not discus if one should be using UI for unit testing)

I created a UI thread and started my component like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));
            plotter = new PlotterWPF();
            plotter.Closed += (s, e) =>
               Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

            plotter.Show();
            plotter.init();

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }));

    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newWindowThread.Start();
```

This works and the plotter appears in screen, my proble is afterwards when I want to send stuff to the plotter I do this:

```
public void debugFrame(Gtec2.Frame frame)
{
    plotter.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        plotter.Plot(frame);
    });
}
```

and it fails because the plotter is null (in the `plotter.Dispatcher...` part)

I tried with Applicaiton.Current.Dispatcher but .. application.Current is null.

I also tried to create the plotter outside the thread but .. I cannot because is not STA. I think there should be a way to let the thing now my Dispatcher is the newWindowThread and the dispatcher.Invoke should happen there but .. I have no clue how to do it ..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread(newWindowThread);
```

This grabs the dispatcher for this particular thread, from there one one can do

```
  dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
  { 
      /*here you can access the plotter */ 
  });
```